# NGINX configuration to preserve URL when doing a proxy redirect from nexus 3 to nexus 2 to use the unzip plugin

Tags: docker, nginx, configuration, nexus

I have migrated to nexus 3 from nexus 2 . But then there is a problem that the nexus 3 does not support the Unzip plugin . So the workaround I came up with was to deploy a nexus 2 container and proxy all the unzip repos to the nexus 2 . Then create a  redirect link when the url ends with ".zip-unzip" it redirects to the nexus 2. This could be done on the nginx configuration . And it should also preserve the nexus3 url but display the nexus2 page.

I tried to do this by defining a location block with a regex to match urls ending with ".zip-unzip" and the proxy pass of the nexus2. But it does not seem to work. I am also not sure how to make the nexus 2 also ssl encrypted at the same time.

server{

```
listen 443 ssl;
server_name mt-nexus.psi-mt.de;
ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/server.key;
include /etc/nginx/custom-errors.conf;  

client_max_body_size 1G;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://nexus3:8081;
    proxy_set_header  Host  $http_host; 
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_read_timeout  900;        


}

location ~ ^"/nexus/(?<section>.+).zip-unzip$" {

proxy_pass http://nexus2:8081/$section.zip-unzip;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";

}       
}
```

I expect that when the url "https://nexus3.xyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/Releases_Unzip/xxx.zip-unzip" is passed, it redirect to the nexus 2 url link "https://nexus2.xyz.com/nexus/content/repositories/Releases_Unzip/xxx.zip-unzip" but have the url preserved of the nexus 3 i.e https://nexus3.xyz.com/...

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by myself. you would have to use a location block but location block does not support the use of "$" when using the proxy pass. So you would have to use a rewrite inside the location block like this.

```
location ~ .zip-unzip/ {
            rewrite ^/nexus/(.*)$ /nexus/$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://nexus4unzip:8081;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

        }
```